# convert from CGImageMetadata to nsdictionary

Tags: ios, metadata, nsdictionary

i tried to convert my 360° metadata image to nsdictionary. every time the app crash when i tried to print a value for an attribute. i wrote this code

CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)imageData, NULL);
    NSArray *metadataArray = nil;

```
if (source) {
    _metaData = CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
    if (_metaData) {
        metadataArray = CFBridgingRelease(CGImageMetadataCopyTags(_metaData));
        CFRelease(_metaData);
    }
    CFRelease(source);
}

NSLog(@"%@",metadataArray[12]);//this is the problem
```

In the output, i find that the type of immutableMetadata is CGImageMetadata not a NSdictionary. How i can convert to nsdictionary please??

Comment: It's not clear. I said on your previous question that `CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex` returns a `CGImageMetadataRef` which is convertible to `NSArray` with `CGImageMetadataCopyTags`. Give a sample of what you want exactly, because converting a array into a dictionary, does it have sense? You can't convert thing like that to expect that bridging will do all the stuff.

Comment: thank you, i understand now , i had a confusion about the returned type of  CGImageMetadataRef which is Nsarray.

Comment: If you want a Dictionary, you can do it, but you may have to do it manually. I logs the `NSArray`, and their are plenty of types that are similar and can be regrouped: "exif", "tiff", "xmp", etc. but I don't know enough to convert them, retrive the type like `kCGImageMetadataPrefixExif`.

Comment: i changed the code like this :CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)imageData, NULL);
    NSArray *metadataArray = nil;
    
    if (source) {
        _metaData = CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
        if (_metaData) {
            metadataArray = CFBridgingRelease(CGImageMetadataCopyTags(_metaData));
            CFRelease(_metaData);
        }
        CFRelease(source);
    }
    
    NSLog(@"%@",metadataArray[12]);

Comment: it show me all the tag line something like this :GPano:PoseHeadingDegrees = 260. i would like to get only the 260 value???

Comment: Are you looking for a specific value? Could you edit your question with the wanted result you want (from a sample version of "metaDaraArray)? I succeed to get almost all values, but that's some work.

Comment: i changed the code below. it show me GPano:PoseHeadingDegrees = 260 when iwrote NSLog(@"%@",metadataArray[12]). I would like to get only the value of the tag.

Comment: You are looking only for `PoseHeadingDegrees`'s value? Then `for (id aRef in metadataArray){CGImageMetadataTagRef currentRef = (__bridge CGImageMetadataTagRef)(aRef); CFStringRef prefix = CGImageMetadataTagCopyPrefix(currentRef); CFStringRef name = CGImageMetadataTagCopyName(currentRef); if ([@"GPano" isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString *)prefix] && [@"PoseHeadingDegrees" isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString *)name]){CFTypeRef value = CGImageMetadataTagCopyValue(currentRef); NSLog(@"Value: %@", value);}` should do the trick?

Comment: thank you it's work. last question i can convert CFTypeRef to int

Comment: If `CFStringRef strValue = CFCopyTypeIDDescription(CFGetTypeID(value));` returns `CFString`, so it can be converted to `NSString`, then to `int` with `NSString *str = (__bridge NSString *)value; int value = [str intValue];` I don't have a `GPano:PoseHeadingDegrees` in my sample image test.

Comment: thank very munch you saved my day. it's works.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about `ImageIO`. It's full of `CF`/`CG` stuff, which may lead to `__bridge` uses.

You are only interested in a value, but if someone is looking for another, it could use that sample code/research:
I looked into `CGImageMetadata.h` for each use of functions related to `CGImageMetadataTagRef` that may be useful.

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)imagedata, NULL);
CGImageMetadataRef imageMetadataRef = CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
NSArray *metadata = CFBridgingRelease(CGImageMetadataCopyTags(imageMetadataRef));
NSLog(@"metadata = %@", metadata);

for (id aRef in metadata)
{
    CGImageMetadataTagRef currentRef = (__bridge CGImageMetadataTagRef)(aRef);
    NSLog(@"Ref: %@", currentRef);
    CGImageMetadataType type = CGImageMetadataTagGetType(currentRef);
    NSLog(@"Type: %d", type);
    CFStringRef nameSpace = CGImageMetadataTagCopyNamespace(currentRef);
    NSLog(@"NameSpace: %@", nameSpace);
    CFStringRef prefix = CGImageMetadataTagCopyPrefix(currentRef);
    NSLog(@"prefix: %@", prefix);
    CFStringRef name = CGImageMetadataTagCopyName(currentRef);
    NSLog(@"name: %@", name);
    CFTypeRef value = CGImageMetadataTagCopyValue(currentRef);
    NSLog(@"Value: %@", value);

    CFStringRef valueTypeStr =  CFCopyTypeIDDescription(CFGetTypeID(value));
    NSLog(@"valueTypeStr: %@", valueTypeStr);

    //Test related to question
    if ([@"GPano" isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString *)prefix] && [@"PoseHeadingDegrees" isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString *)name])
    {
        NSString *str = (__bridge NSString *)value;
        NSLog(@"Str: %@", str);
        NSLog(@"Int: %d", [str intValue]);
    }
}
```

To know if the value is convertible to a more "known" object, like `NSString` (<=> `CFString`), `NSArray` (<=> `CFArray`), `NSDictionary` (<=> `CFDictionary`), I looked at `CFStringRef valueTypeStr =  CFCopyTypeIDDescription(CFGetTypeID(value));` (or you can also do a "quicker test" with related question: [Determining what a CFTypeRef is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471964/determining-what-a-cftyperef-is)).

It's all "manually" done, I'm quite surprised that there is no conversion from `CGImageMetadataTagRef` to a more "known" object (and not `struct`), maybe there is, I didn't read the whole headers of `CGImageMetadata.h`, so there may be a quicker way, but I thought that even using "old school" approach, by digging could be useful for another user with a related question, helping him/her to find quickly what's he/she is looking for.

To answer your initial question: `CGImageMetadata` to `NSDictionary`, if there is no "easy conversion" tool, and with the "digging" approach, it's won't make a lot of sense, because the interesting method `CGImageMetadataCopyTags` returns a `NSArray` (or `CFArray`).
But since a lot of `CGImageMetadataTagRef` prefix are the same, you may be interested, by doing manually the following dictionary:
`@{prefix1:@[stuff10, stuff11, etc.], prefix2:@[stuff20, stuff21, etc.]}`

Answer (score 2):

Swift

```
extension CGImageSource {

    func metadata() -> Dictionary<String, Any>? {

        guard let imageMetadata = CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex(self, 0, .none) else {
            return .none
        }

        guard let tags = CGImageMetadataCopyTags(imageMetadata) else {
            return .none
        }

        var result = [String: Any]()
        for tag in tags as NSArray {
            let tagMetadata = tag as! CGImageMetadataTag
            if let cfName = CGImageMetadataTagCopyName(tagMetadata) {
                let name = String(cfName)
                let value = CGImageMetadataTagCopyValue(tagMetadata)
                result[name] = value
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that to be sure the tag is a unique key in the dictionary you probably want to `let cfPrefix = CGImageMetadataTagCopyPrefix(tagMetadata)` and then `let name = String(cfPrefix) + "::"  + String(cfName)`