# Convert CATextLayer font to UIFont

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

`CATextLayer.font` property is an opaque `CFTypeRef`. Is there a way of converting that reference to a `UIFont`? I don't mind if it returns an optional UIFont.

Comment: It's `May be either a CTFont, a CGFont, an instance of NSFont (macOS only), or a string naming the font` according to the doc. So https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714858/iphone-convert-ctfont-to-uifont, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205709/how-to-convert-cgfontref-to-uifont etc.? Depending on the type, function equivalent name should be available in Swift. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471964/determining-what-a-cftyperef-is to get the type?

Comment: Since you created the text layer and configured it, how can you not know what font you assigned it?

Comment: Easy. This is part of a general framework, and I use text layers in several places, with different fonts. In fact, my answer below is a modified version of a protocol implementation that requires a `get` and a `set`. No assumptions are made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote the following extension which should handle: `CTFont`, `CGFont`, string name or `UIFont`:

```
extension CATextLayer {
    public var typeFace:UIFont? {
        let name:String
        switch font {
        case let ctFont as CTFont :
            // If you assign a UIFont to CATextLayer.font
            // it is implicitly converted to CTFont,
            // so this case will be called.
            guard let _name = CTFontCopyName(ctFont, kCTFontPostScriptNameKey) else {
                return nil
            }
            name = _name as NSString as String
        case let cgFont as CGFont :
            guard let _name = cgFont.postScriptName else {
                return nil
            }
            name = _name as NSString as String
        case let string as NSString :
            name = string as String
        case let string as String :
            name = string
        default:
            return nil
        }
        return UIFont(name:name, size:fontSize)
    }
}
```

On a side note, I found this comment in docs inaccurate:

> In iOS, you cannot assign a UIFont object to this property.

From my tests I was able to set a `UIFont` on `CATextLayer.font` and it appears to work fine.

---

EDIT

It turns out when you assign a `UIFont` to `CATextLayer.font` it is converted to a `CTFont` behind the scenes, so in order to get the `UIFont` back out it's necessary to convert from `CTFont` to `UIFont` (which my code does). Simply casting to `UIFont` would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
let font : UIFont = layer.font as! UIFont
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is OK only a UIFont is assigned in the first place, in any other case it will fail. On a side note, I would not force cast, since my return type is `UIFont?` it can just `return self.font as? UIFont`.