# How to detect if variable type is CGColor

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having this issue, that on old react native versions `borderColor` is `CGColorRef` and on new one it's `UIColor`.

Is there a way to check `CGColorRef` variable type? Objective-c doesn't allow me to use isKindOfClass with `CGColorRef`.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
if([rctView.borderColor isKindOfClass:[UIColor class]]) { // that's where I'm wrong
   _borderColor = rctView.borderColor; // assign UIColor to UIColor variable
} else {
   _borderColor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:rctView.borderColor]; // assign converted CGColor to UIColor
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: see this may be it helps you : [How to compare UIColors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970475/how-to-compare-uicolors)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471964/determining-what-a-cftyperef-is

Comment: Does reactnative returns `borderColor` as `id`? I didn't understand the problem. Compiler anyway will make error if you try assign `CGColorRef` to `UIColor *` variable. So just update it and fix all errors ‍♂️

Comment: Are you using simultaneously the old and new react native versions? If not, just stick with the type consumed by the react native version you're using.

Comment: The main issue is, that I have to support both of the versions - old and new

Answer (score 0):

There is noway to make it out.
UIColor belongs foundation, CGColorRef is derived from CFTypeRef, belongs to corefoundation.
a method in foundation or corefoundation can not be used in the other. that means you can't use foundation's or corefoundation's method to detect the variable type.
below the foundation and corefoundation, there is some method to use in both, but in that level, the variable just means a memory address.